# Advance query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.1

I have the following models:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

How can I create a query to get 5 books, each one of them from different author?

Another condition is that if I have less than 5 authors, I should still get 5 books, one for each author and the rest of the books could be from any of those authors.

Comment: Please post what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Hi Josh. I had an idea base on http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge, but this just solve the case where there are more than 5 authors

Answer (score 0):

Let's get the 5 random authors first:

```
authors = Author.all.order('random()').limit(5)
```

Now let's try to get one book for each one

```
chosen_books = []
authors.each do |author|
  chosen_books << author.books.order('random()').first
end
```

Now, we can check if we're still short books

```
if chosen_books.size < 5
  already_chosen_book_ids = chosen_books.map(&:id)
  limit = 5 - chosen_books.size
  extra_books = Book.where(author: authors).where('id NOT IN (?)', already_chosen_book_ids).order('random()').limit(limit)
  chosen_books = chosen_books.concat(extra_books.to_a)
end
```